# Linkage Error ork.security.config.method.InternalInterceptMethodsBeanDefinitionDecorator.createInterceptorDefinition

Tags: java, spring, security, jar, linkage

I got this error when I am updating spring version from 3.1.0 to 4.3.0

```
 Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.springframework.security.config.method.InternalInterceptMethodsBeanDefinitionDecorator.createInterceptorDefinition(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, org/springframework/security/config/method/InternalInterceptMethodsBeanDefinitionDecorator, and its superclass loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type ork.security.config.method.InternalInterceptMethodsBeanDefinitionDecorator.createInterceptorDefinition(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition; used in the signature
        at org.springframework.security.config.method.InterceptMethodsBeanDefinitionDecorator.<init>(InterceptMethodsBeanDefinitionDecorator.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.<init>(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
        ... 31 more
```

**Old jars are**

- spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-expression-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-core-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-core-tiger-2.0.5.jar

**New Jars are**

- spring-core-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-oxm-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- castor-xml-1.4.1.jar
- spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-beans-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-expression-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-support-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-instrument-tomcat-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-core-2.0.8.jar
- spring-security-core-tiger-2.0.8.jar

Comment: Stop mixing Spring Security versins... You have 4.1.3 and 4.2.0 jars...

Comment: It wast given here by mistake, actually I'm using spring-security-core-2.0.8.jar and spring-security-core-tiger-2.0.8.jar, and no other spring jars, but still having the problem.

Comment: That is not designed to work with spring 4 (if it would even work)... That is an ancient version of Spring Security... I would however start with removing some of your xml libraries (looks like adding caster-xml broke things, and if you resolve those you probably run into issues with API changes between Spring 3.1 and 4.3).

Comment: Ok, Thanks for ur info. So, I must remove the caster-xml right?

Comment: Can u pls tellme, which spring security version is more compatible and stable with spring 4.3 ?